# Aidez-moi à comprendre ce que les gens disent dans ce podcast

Tags: oral

Bonjour !

Je suis en train de transcrire un podcast fascinant pour un projet mais je ne comprends pas quelques phrases que disent les interviewés, dont beaucoup ont un accent ou parlent très vite.

1. [2:56](https://soundcloud.com/nouvelles-ecoutes/rediffusion-splash-limmigration-nuit-elle-a-leconomie?in=nouvelles-ecoutes/sets/splash#t=2:56) : 1. (ce que je comprends pas est indiqué par **[???]**): « Ça nous a pris presque 12 jours pour déplacer 100 kilomètres entre Raqqa et la frontière de la Turquie. Comme il y avait plein de barrages à chaque 5 km, chaque 10 km et c'était contrôlé par plusieurs groupes, du **[???]**, de Daech, du gouvernement, du **[???]**, donc à chaque fois on raconte une histoire différente pour passer la frontière ... »
2. [5:54](https://soundcloud.com/nouvelles-ecoutes/rediffusion-splash-limmigration-nuit-elle-a-leconomie?in=nouvelles-ecoutes/sets/splash#t=5:54) : « Comme je vous disais entre temps, **[???]**, j'ai fait des études de sociologie et l'économie. C'était dans une grand banque, j'étais sous-directrice. Du coup j'ai tout quitté. Voilà, je suis venue sans réfléchir. »
3. [12:31](https://soundcloud.com/nouvelles-ecoutes/rediffusion-splash-limmigration-nuit-elle-a-leconomie?in=nouvelles-ecoutes/sets/splash#t=12:31) « J'ai postulé. Ils ont pris presque 300 personnes pour faire **[???]** et on était tous des agences de sécurité VIP, c'est-à-dire dans la tribune présidentielle et VIP ... »
4. [13:35](https://soundcloud.com/nouvelles-ecoutes/rediffusion-splash-limmigration-nuit-elle-a-leconomie?in=nouvelles-ecoutes/sets/splash#t=13:35) « Quand **[???]** la chocolatière j'avais 50 ans, déjà un âge où on peut pas trouver facilement un travail. Mes expériences en Turquie c'était déjà passé. Je connaissais bien le propriétaire ici et ma mère elle m'a dit puisque c'est comme ça **[???]** C'est la banque qui nous donne d'accord. On achète le magasin parce qu'il y avait une clientèle qui me connaissait bien ... »
5. [16:58](https://soundcloud.com/nouvelles-ecoutes/rediffusion-splash-limmigration-nuit-elle-a-leconomie?in=nouvelles-ecoutes/sets/splash#t=16:58) : « Oui, maintenant c'est le mois de juin, juste **[???]** le travail ... »

C'est tout. J'apprécie beaucoup votre aide !

Comment: Je n'ai pas compris tout ce qui manque mais d'autres pourront certainement compléter. Au passage je corrige quelques erreurs... (1) des Kurdes ;  (2) des rebelles ; (3)  (ce sont des initiales je pense, probablement celles d'une école de commerce) ; (4) l'Euro 2016 ; (5) quand elle est partie en liquidation la chocolatière... j'avais 45 ans déjà un âge où on peut pas trouver.... ; (6) Je connaissais bien la propriétaire d'ici, et mon mari il a dit puisque c'est comme ça on va le voir, s'ils suivent, si la banque elle nous  l'accord ; (7) juste après Pâques le travail ça commence à baisser

Comment: J'ai oublié un mot au passage  (6) Je connaissais bien la propriétaire d'ici, et mon mari il a dit puisque c'est comme ça on va le voir, s'ils suivent, si la banque elle nous donne  l'accord ;

Comment: Some items in your accepted answer are wrong and some are missing. I did not write an answer because the question is not really of the type we usually accept on French Language.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not a transcription service.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

2:56 - plusieurs groupes, du Kurd, du Daech, du gouvernement, du rebelle, donc ...

5:54 - comme je vous disait entre temps, j'ai fais l'université,

12:31 - pour faire l'ordre de ... ? (incompréhensible)

13:35 - Quand j'ai porté en liquidation la chocolatière (l'orateur fais des erreurs de language, la vrai signification est "Quand j'ai mis la chocolaterie en liquidation judiciaire")

- Puisque c'est comme ça, on va la voir, si ils nous ont suivis. C'est la banque ...

16:58 - Juste après Paques le travail

Comment: 13 : 35 ne peut pas être ça. La locutrice ne peut pas avoir mis la chocolaterie en liquidation vu qu'elle n'était pas propriétaire.

Comment: Merci beaucoup, Worlor and @Laure ! Je comprends maintenant.